# How to formally establish the argument whether programming could be a new form of literacy or not?

Tags: reference-request

Reading and writing was invented only recently, and it took time to propagate worldwide; even today there will be millions [illiterate](https://www.projectliteracy.com/you-wont-believe-how-many-people-cant-read-sentence) people - hard to imagine.

Then, there are about 20 millions of programmers worldwide - individuals which can write symbols in a way that computer can perform some action processing them. I think over time there will be more.

I do not even know how to establish the argument that ability to write code is sort of new literacy - or how to prove the opposite?

Or which philosophical thought on it is there already.

I try therefore the *reference request* tag.

Hope this question makes sense.

Comment: I think most people would accept the phrase "computer-illiterate" without much effort. Perhaps you really want to argue that computer illiteracy is as problematic as reading & writing illiteracy?

Comment: literacy from the [latin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/litteratus#Latin) computer illiteracy more of an idiom, just my two cents, thanks

Comment: @user3293056 how do you mean?

Comment: @DanielGoldman yes and possibly exponentially more problematic

Comment: To me, the interesting philosophical issues may revolve around the "hidden" nature of code, it seems that code's ultimate goal is to make things more user friendly in the ordinary language of the final user. Of course, we have also developed more user friendly coding language. This seems to call for a lot of opinions, which may be unavoidable. The reference request idea is good, if there are any!

Comment: @J.Doe an idiom cos people say that phrase without two thoughts.

Comment: @user3293056 ok I see - therefore I do not use the term "computer literacy" which implies using digital appliances AFAIK but "coding/programming literacy"

Comment: makes sense, wasn't meant as a refutation of your request @J.Doe i don't know you well enough to guess if you're implying that coding illiteracy equates to some form of slavery. i mean on that "riff" suppose that any super human intelligence/s (guh) will treat humanity fairly uniform

Comment: " coding illiteracy equates to some form of slavery" very interesting catch I really do not feel related to, but why? normal illiteracy isn't actually slavery - I thought like, being literate gives you more possibilities, well freedom but not in a sense like an opposite to slavery?

Comment: @J.Doe cool, i agree. my original comment was just to stress that probably *most* people can get to grips with basic coding. think it mostly taps working memory? all the best, move to chat if you want to keep chatting, apologies

Comment: One of the definitions of "literacy" is ["competence or knowledge in a specified area."](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/literacy) What you're asking about directly follows from that definition, so I do not understand what issue you're having trying to "form an argument" that the ability to read and write a program is a form of literacy, that seems a priori given the definitions of the words you're using. This question does not seem to be about philosophy at all, just definitions.

Comment: Programming languages are [languages](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language), the definition of literacy means the ability to read and write a language, therefore people are either literate or illiterate in regards to a programming language. But what at all does this have to do with philosophy? I don't think this is a good question for the site because it is just asking about definitions of words, not even philosophy words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With any category argument, you need to start with a definition. While a dictionary definition might work, it is usually more useful to find expert definitions. I would see if you can find some papers and academic quality books on the topic of literacy. See if your library has something like [The Anthropology of Literacy](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9781444396713.ch10/summary).

If you can find a recognized definition which includes more than just reading and writing, and especially if it already would imply that understanding of programming is a form of literacy.

One argument is that programming languages are just that: languages. If that is the case, then you can start directly from the definition "knowing how to read and write a language." I think most people would accept that definition and it is the argument that I would use.

One way you can bolster the argument is through the citation of legal cases which are consistent with your position. This [article](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2015/04/remembering-case-established-code-speech) cites a pertinent case and this specific quote from the case may be the linchpin in your argument:

> This court can find no meaningful difference between computer
>   language, particularly high-level languages as defined above, and
>   German or French....Like music and mathematical equations, computer
>   language is just that, language, and it communicates information
>   either to a computer or to those who can read it..

As far as the US courts are concerned, Java is no different than French. If you can understand and write Java code, you're literate in Java. If you cannot understand or write code in any programming language, then you are illiterate as far as that is concerned.

**Foundations**

There is always a question of whether or not an argument is valid. As long as a position is logically derived from a foundation, then it is valid, up to that foundation. If someone is not willing to accept SCOTUS rulings on the meaning of a word, then we have to see if we can use a different argument, but at the very least, it is a good starting point, and the argument itself made by the justices might work as material towards a modified argument.

Comment: "As far as the US courts are concerned, Java is no different than French." you made my day @Daniel Goldman, thank you!  And very helpful input. I will wait a litte bit and possibly accept your answer as correct/fulfilling - until smb will provide the reference to a source nailing down that line of argument completely.

Comment: Honestly, I had been looking into the legal aspect of programming languages and protocols for something else, so that's the only reason why I'm familiar with it. Basically, I wanted to see if it would be legal to write a ground up protocol compliant server-client pair that used the same protocol and file types as World of Warcraft.

Comment: I don't know if this approach is helpful in philosophy.  I doubt it.

Comment: The goal is to convince someone of the usage of a word. There may never be an absolute in a philosophical discussion. All we can do is find a common foundation and build from there. If a person is willing to accept a SCOTUS position on the nature of programming languages, then you're good to go.

Comment: J. Doe, are there any more concerns that you would like me to address in my answer?